# Cannot user easy_install or install pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I am a noob here. Because I need to use Python 2.7 for work, I created another user login and tried to re-setup my dev environment. I have reinstalled python 2.7 using brew but I couldn't get easy_install or work and my system cannot find where pip is. Much frustration here, hope someone can help!

[image]

I have already tried to install pip and the system still cannot find it:
[image]

Comment: Can't find pip probably cause you don't have pip in this account. Google how to install pip or easy_install.

Comment: @dietbacon See my update, I indeed have installed pip.

Comment: it didn't return anything.